I can not download only jcenter support dependencies
I added
jcenter()
maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") } 

into settings.gradle.kts file but it did not work. I want to use this library com.github.devlight:infinitecycleviewpager:1.0.2.
Error Text:
Failed to resolve: com.github.devlight:infinitecycleviewpager:1.0.2

I faced this issue:


JCenter has been finally shut down mid of August 2024. Use a different version from a different repo or migrate to a different library.

did u fixed it if fixed then update it with solution

You can search for that library on major search engines. If you do that, you will see that the library has not been updated in eight years and was only ever published to JCenter. As is noted in a comment, JCenter has been shut down.
The best solution is to not use this library, given its age and lack of maintenance.
The next-best solution is for you do fork the library and build it yourself, such as in a module in your own project.

FWIW, I wrote more about this situation in my blog.
